# Recover Deployed Contract on Remix

Tags: remix, contract-deployment

I am working on the text, Mastering Ethereum and I deployed a contract and sent it test ether. However, for unrelated reasons I had to restart my browser, upon returning the only way I could continue was to launch a new contract cause I could see no way to continue or retrieve the last account in remix.
Hence my question, is there a way to "contniue" working on a contract? or I can search and bring it back with the same account number in Remix?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, as long as you know the address of the deployed contract.

To start, make sure that the same contract that you deployed (and are trying to interact with) is in the IDE section on the left side. You will need that there in order to correctly read the ABI.

When this is done, click on the `run` tab on the right side. Here, you will see two options, `Deploy` or `At Address`. Enter the address of the deployed contract in the `At Address` field, and click on it.

You will then see the deployed contract and you will be able to interact with it.